# Can't get Spyder to work with Git: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, git, spyder

Is there any documentation on how Spyder works with Git? Note I am talking about GIT, on my PC only, not github.

Spyder's website doesn't really say much: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/projects.html#working-with-version-control

I must say I am new to Git, but I have installed Git for Windows: https://gitforwindows.org/

I have created a repository in the same folder in which I have created a Spyder project

I have created a test.py file

if, in the Spyder project pane, I right click on the file and click **'browse repository' I get:**

> Error parsing revisions: unknown revision HEAD

If I click on commit, it doesn't work. Certainly being new to Git doesn't help, but what am I doing wrong? Is there any documentation anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell easily what your specific issue is, but it may help if you can access the `git log` for that directory. If there are no entries, perhaps you can try to add all the files in the directory to staged: `git add .`, commit `git commit -m "<your commit message>"`and then see if you can "browse repository" in the Spyder UI. The error isn't that helpful but if there are no revisions, perhaps its an edge case Spyder does not expect.

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Right now (March 2019) our Git support is very limited and not well tested.

We have plans to improve that in the future, but until then I think it's better for you to use Git in a terminal.

Comment: is there now support for git in SPYDER?....https://stackoverflow.com/users/438386/carlos-cordoba

Comment: No, there isn't yet, sorry.

Comment: Yes, most probably for Spyder 5, to be released next year.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: Hi, I have not used Github or any similar tools so far and I would like to use it for versioning of the code. Can I use Spyder together with Github such that Spyder automatically loads the files from Github?

Comment: @PeterBe, no, that's not possible right now, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Carlos. Do you know whether Spyder is planning to do that? Further do you know why Spyder does not support GitHub? For me this is kind of strange as Github is extremely popular and widely used amongst developers.

Comment: We'll try to support interacting with Github sometime in the future. The problem is we're a small team (6 people) working part time in the project, and we already have a ton of functionality that we need to constantly maintain and give support for.

Answer (score 1):

I Use spyder with Anaconda. At first I was not able to work with Git as i do in R studio. Below are the steps that i have taken to work with Git seamlessly.

Step 1) Download and Install [Git](https://gitforwindows.org/)

Step 2) Open Anaconda Prompt. Type below command

```
conda install -c anaconda git
```

[Image:Anaconda prompt after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYPT5.png)

step 3) Open Git GUI and Create Repositry in the required **"FilePath"** with **"FileName"**

Step 4) Launch Spyder application from Anaconda. Go to Projects in Menubar and click **New project**

Step 5) Select **Existing Directory** in location goto **"FilePath"** [where Git Repositry was created in step 3] and select directory with **"FileName"**[Git Repositry name] and click on **create**.

Now you can write scripts and commit by right clicking on the file from project explorer.
[Image:Spyder window with Git integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D86sW.png)

Answer (score 0):

As of February 2021, @Jeevankrishna's response worked for me in Spyder 4.2.0, running out of conda! Thanks so much!
Just wanted to add that now, instead of right clicking on the file from project explorer, Spyder devs have added git functionalities in the IPython console (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6105)

I was able to run `!git add .`, `!git commit -m ""`, `!git push`, and it seems other basic git commands work with the `!` prepended

Answer (score 0):

The git functionality you are referring to is a standard feature of iPython and not specifically enabled by the Spyder team. There is some git support in Spyder. In the "Files" window, right click on a file and the menu options "Commit" and "Browse Repository" are available. This requires that "gitk" be installed